# English regulators?

Tags: academia

Does anyone know if English has a regulator as Spanish does? We have "Real Academia Española" (Royal Spanish Academy) it seems English doesn't have one (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_language_regulators). Even Klingon has one (he he).

Comment: Well, there's always [The Academy](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/academy.html).

Comment: You are looking at it.

Comment: ...... Humpty Dumpty

Comment: If their were one, we would pay it no attention.